# Setting up a linked server from SQL Server 2005 to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, postgresql, linked-server

Since I struggled a bit with this one and couldn't find a good online source with simple steps, here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download [ODBCng](https://projects.commandprompt.com/public/odbcng/wiki/Downloads) and install it
2. Set up a System DNS that connects to your PostgreSQL server. I named mine POSTGRESQL, which is used in the next couple of steps
3. Run the following code in SSMS to create the linked server. This assumes a PostgreSQL instance on the local machine (hence localhost):

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
       @server = N'POSTGRESQL',
       @srvproduct=N'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Driver',
       @provider=N'MSDASQL',
       @datasrc='PostgreSQL',
       @location='localhost',
       @catalog='public'
4. Run the following code in SSMS to create a login mapping for the linked server:

   EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
       @rmtsrvname=N'POSTGRESQL',
       @useself=N'False',
       @locallogin=NULL,
       @rmtuser='',
       @rmtpassword=''
5. Issue statements such as:

   SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(POSTGRESQL, 'select my_column from my_table limit 10')

I had to use the double-quote

Answer (score 1):

You can use PGNP OLE DB provider for PostgreSQL (pgoledb.com). See example on how to configure Linked Server at http://www.pgoledb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6).

It is very high performance and scalable driver. We use it to work with tens of millions rows tables.

Regards,
Carlos